# Loop through a folder of XML files?

Tags: php

I have a folder with XML files in, which I want to loop through.

I've already created the XML parser which works when specifying one xml file to load from, but I kind of want to wrap what I've written in a sort of foreach loop situation, where it looks up the folder name, loops through each XML file and then deletes them once they've been looped through.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but where are you stuck?

Comment: wheres your code then?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) function.

Specifically:

```
$files = glob("directory/*.xml");
```

Then `foreach` over this filename list.

For nested folders, investigate [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator).